# JOIN order impacts performance in 3 table inner join select query

Tags: mysql, join

I am joining 3 tables, a, b and c, all of which have a common indexed key field, xID. If I join a to b then b to c, the query runs in about 2 seconds; if I join a to b then a to c, the query times out after  running for tens of minutes. a is small and b and c are large (1:70:90)

Using explain, the second query uses a join buffer on the second join and indicates >1M rows against tables b and c, but the first only >1M on b. Varying join order, it is always slow with the small table a in the centre between the two large tables b and c. Can anyone explain why?

Q1

```
select count(distinct a.ID) 
from a 
join b on a.xID = b.xID 
join c on b.xID = c.xID;
```

versus
Q2

```
select count(distinct a.ID)
from a
join b on a.xID = b.xID
join c on a.xID = c.xID
```

I expected both queries to be give same count and take about the same time, but this is not the case. Q1 = 2secs; Q2 never completes.

Comment: If you do find that a particular order of joins works better you might want to consider using optimizer hints to keep the optimizer from trying to outsmart itself each time it sees that query.

Comment: What have you learned & applied re the basics of optimizing queries, including from the manual?

Comment: philipxy, usually, I would think I was missing an index, but for simple queries, and with indexes on the join keys and a count of a primary key, as a rule, I have learned to trust the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this finding.

I have 3 tables, each comprising 2 columns - (id an auto-incrementing PRIMARY KEY, and xid an indexed integer).

table_a comprises 128 rows, with 78 distinct xids

table_b comprises 8192 rows, with 5573 distinct xids

table_c comprises 1048576 rows, with 640468 distinct xids.

Regardless of how I join them together, the following query takes roughly 1/10th of a second, and returns the same result:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)n 
  FROM table_a a 
  JOIN table_b b 
    ON b.xid = a.xid 
  JOIN table_c c 
    ON c.id = a.id -- [or c.id = b.id]
```

Comment: That's what I was expecting too. I will go back to the data to look for anything unusual.